# Pandas apply filter dynamically

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a complex issue to solve.
I have a dataframe like:

[image]

and the output desired is:

[image]

So it's basically logically grouping ie)

for first row: it's only a with a hence only 1 under a and remaining 0

for second row: it's a with b and hence 1 and 1 and rest 0 etc

Next based on the new df:

for each row, i have to filter a dataframe(say df3) eg:

[image]

1st row: df3.loc[(df3['name']=='a')]['flag'].count()

2nd row: df3.loc[(df3['name']=='a') & (df3['name']=='b')]['flag'].count()

3rd row: df3.loc[(df3['name']=='a') & (df3['name']=='b') & & (df3['name']=='c')]['flag'].count()

Any idea how to achieve this?

I am trying to generate those filters in a loop and then apply to df3 dataframe

Comment: So logic is for first `a` row only `1` in `a` column, for first `b` only `1` in `b` column, for first `c` only `1` in `c` column ? And all another rows are from `1,1` to `1,1,1,1` ?

Comment: that's correct. Like a logical 'and' condition

Comment: `for each row, i have to filter a dataframe(say df3)` ? How looks `df3` ?

Comment: df3 is another df which has a column having data like a,b,c,d which i will use to filter based on the conditions

Comment: just edited my post and added structure for df3, i will use df3 just to filter records based on dynamically generated filters using df1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do that.
So using 'eval' on dataframe.
I was able to generate a string using a for loop and was able to pass that string in an eval function.
eg:

```
for i in range(0,len(df.columns)):
        if len(df.columns[i])==1:
            uu=[]
            st = column + "==" +"'"+str(df.columns[i][0])+"'"
            #print(column)
            uu.append(st)
            uu2 = ' | '.join([str(elem) for elem in uu]) 
            # uu2 string will directly go to df to get evaluated
            aa = df[df.eval(uu2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(0, index=list('aaaabbbb'), columns=list('abcd'))
print (df1)
   a  b  c  d
a  0  0  0  0
a  0  0  0  0
a  0  0  0  0
a  0  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  0
```

First create lower triangle matrix by [`numpy.tril`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html) and [`numpy.ones`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html):

```
size = len(df1.columns)
         
a = np.tril(np.ones((size, size), dtype=int))
print (a)
[[1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

Then fill diagonal values to `1` by [`numpy.fill_diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html)

```
b = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=int)
np.fill_diagonal(b, 1)
print (b)
[[1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]]
```

Repeat array `a` by number of columns with [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) nad obverwrite each `size` row by indexing with values of array `b`:

```
c = np.tile(a, (size, 1))
c[::size] = b
print (c)
[[1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

Last convert to `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(c, columns=df1.columns, index = np.repeat(df1.columns, size))
print (df)
   a  b  c  d
a  1  0  0  0
a  1  1  0  0
a  1  1  1  0
a  1  1  1  1
b  0  1  0  0
b  1  1  0  0
b  1  1  1  0
b  1  1  1  1
c  0  0  1  0
c  1  1  0  0
c  1  1  1  0
c  1  1  1  1
d  0  0  0  1
d  1  1  0  0
d  1  1  1  0
d  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: That works!!! First task accomplished :)
Thanks a lot

Comment: @AkshatShreemali - Unfortunately still not understand second task. Can you explain why is `0` for first 2 rows and 1 for third row in `df3` ? Or in another words, what is expected output from `df3` by solution above?

Comment: first of all, thanks a lot and i really appreciate your help.
So for df3, i just have to filter the data in it iteratively based on the conditions created by the new dataframe. eg: first row of the new dataframe will have records for df3 filtered by condition: df3['name']=='a' and then second row willl be df3['name'='a' and 'b' and then 3rd row will be df3['name']=='a and b and c like that.
df3 will be just used to filter based on the "and" filters

Comment: If we can just generate those filters dynamically based on the created dataframe. I am not able to generate these filters dynamically.

Comment: @AkshatShreemali - Unfortunately still not understand second task. Can you explain why is 0 for first 2 rows and 1 for third row in df3 ?

Comment: @AkshatShreemali - Maybe my main problem is not underatand what are input data from `df3` and what are expected output from `df3` ? I am lost here.

Comment: @AkshatShreemali - What mean `df3.loc[(df3['col']=='a')]['flag'].count()` ? There is no column `col` in `df3`, not understand it.

Comment: just updated my post again.  i have to get the filters for all permutations of the dataframe (df1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224518/discussion-between-jezrael-and-akshat-shreemali).